# Which compilation flags should I use to avoid run time errors

Tags: c++, c, compiler-warnings, compiler-flags, sequence-points

Just learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963156/why-doesnt-gcc-throw-a-warning-in-this-example#43963156) that `-Wsequence-point` comiplation flag will pop a warning when the code can invoke UB. I tried it on a statement like

```
int x = 1;
int y = x+ ++x;
```

and it worked very nicely. Until now I have compiled with `gcc` or `g++` only using `-ansi -pedantic -Wall` . Do you have any other helpful flags to make the code more safe and robust?

Comment: `int y = x+ ++x;` -> `int y = 2*x + 1`

Comment: @InternetAussie This is not what OP's asking, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought that this is UB and because it's UB, it's not 2x+1, at least not by definition. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of `gcc`, to learn what flags it supports, and which of those would be useful to you?

Comment: `-ansi` does not make your code more safe or more robust, it just makes it use an outdated version of the dialect. Use `-std=<version>` for compliance with a standard of your choosing, for instance `-std=c99` or `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @spectras I used _-ansi_  for historical reasons. The new flags are those who I want to make my code robust

Comment: Why don't you have a read through the g++ documentation? Most available warning flags are listed there.

Comment: @CIsForCookies I think his comment was intended to show you how to rewrite your code with no UB.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh, thanks :) I started doubting my understanding of UB...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11720263/3212865 (basically the OP asks how to blanket-enable all warnings and the answer explains why such an option does not exist and would not make sense, and it's up to you to pick what is and isn't an error in your specific project).

Comment: @spectras thx! didn't see this one. but still, I wonder what flags are considered good and helpful, and what flags will just overwhelm me with useless data

Comment: For most practical purposes, `-Wall` is more than enough, sometimes `-Wextra` as well. Beyond that, manually picking specific context-dependent warnings _can_ make sense. Consider `-Werror` for dev build as well, if you want to enforce a no-warning policy.

Comment: `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` helps you, but does not avoid any run-time error, which you probably would never be able to achieve using static code analysis.

Comment: @alk what do you mean? by telling me _operation on 'x' may be undefined_ I can guess that my run time error was caused by the line touching _x_.

Comment: These are the compiler flags *I* commonly use with `g++`: `-std=c++14 -O3 -ggdb3 -march=core2 -fno-common -pipe -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wvla -Wreorder -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wpacked -Wcast-align -Wenum-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winvalid-pch -Woverlength-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -Woverflow -Wsequence-point -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wtrigraphs -finput-charset=UTF-8 -Wpacked-bitfield-compat -Wlogical-op -Wsync-nand -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wnoexcept`

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's a nice lid st you've got there! Aren't some of these covered by -Wall or -Wextra?

Comment: @Jonas I don't believe so. Otherwise I wouldn't have added them explicitly ;-)

Comment: In general "*run-time error*" refers to an error occurring during .. well: "run-time" of the program, that is not during compilation (or linking time). So if you faced a compilation or linking error, you'd never face a run-time error, as the program would never run, as you faced a compilation or linking error. :-)

Comment: This surely won't stop the run-time error, but afterwards it may be the best indication I'll have from where to start looking... that's what I meant. And this is only a warning, so I would have a compiler-warning that could turn into a run-time error :)

Comment: ' +nobugs ' ........:)

Comment: Some invaluable things are Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer (UBsan) and Address Sanitizer (Asan), available as plugins for GCC and Clang. These can catch types of runtime errors - like buffer/indexing overflows, use of objects before construction or after destruction, etc - that compile-time warnings can't. Why can't they? Well, take your pick: the code is valid as long as it's given valid input, or it's bad but the Standard doesn't mandate a diagnostic, or determining whether an error will occur from the code alone without running it is non-trivial (something-something halting problem something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alk summed up, use these flags:

> -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion

---

First, I think you don't want to use the `-ansi` flag, as suggested in [Should I use "-ansi" or explicit "-std=..." as compiler flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300114/should-i-use-ansi-or-explicit-std-as-compiler-flags)

Secondly, [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) seems to be quite useful too, as suggested in [-Wextra how useful is it really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888404/wextra-how-useful-is-it-really)

Thirdly, [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion) seems also useful, as suggested in [Can I make GCC warn on passing too-wide types to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310108/can-i-make-gcc-warn-on-passing-too-wide-types-to-functions)

Fourthly, [`-pedantic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) is also helpul,
 as suggested in [What is the purpose of using -pedantic in GCC/G++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855121/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-pedantic-in-gcc-g-compiler).

Lastly, enabling `-Wall` should be fine in this case, so I am pretty doubtful about what you said.

Example with [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc):

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ cat main.c 
int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = x+ ++x;
    return 0;
}
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:4:16: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'x' [-Wunsequenced]
    int y = x+ ++x;
            ~  ^
main.c:4:9: warning: unused variable 'y' [-Wunused-variable]
    int y = x+ ++x;
        ^
2 warnings generated.
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Example with [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b), same version:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ cp main.c main.cpp
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
main.cpp:4:16: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'x'
      [-Wunsequenced]
    int y = x+ ++x;
            ~  ^
main.cpp:4:9: warning: unused variable 'y' [-Wunused-variable]
    int y = x+ ++x;
        ^
2 warnings generated.
```

---

Relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935793/2411320) of mine, that Wall saves the day once more with a similar problem.

Comment: Note: `-Wall` does not enable *all* warnings - far from it in fact. Personally I'd always add `-Wextra` as well, at a minimum. But even that still doesn't enable all useful warnings, there are many others that you may want to enable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Isn't there something similar to an FAQ concerning the compiler flags from `gcc` ? Seems like a pretty common configuration problem to me..